# Adding setShowAsActionFlags() to MenuItem is causing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'm adding items to the action bar programmatically.  I am using [ViewBadger()](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) to badge the icon in the action bar.  I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to set MenuItem.setShowAsActionFlags().  If I comment out this line, I get no errors.  The exception is not happening in code I can see, but in system code.

From the logcat, the error occurs at ViewGroup.addInArray(). What could be the problem?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;

    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
    container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    int count = 0;



    //Battery///////////////////////////
    MenuItem menuItemBattery = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Battery Level");
    menuItemBattery.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_battery));
    count++;
    //menuItemBattery.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);


    // The badge view requires target view (iconView in this case)
    // to have a ViewGroup parent
    ImageButton iconViewBattery = new ImageButton(this);
    iconViewBattery.setImageDrawable(menuItemBattery.getIcon());
    container.addView(iconViewBattery);
    BadgeView badge2 = new BadgeView(this, iconViewBattery);
    if (batteryPercent > 30) {      
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    } else if (batteryPercent > 10 && batteryPercent < 31) {
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (batteryPercent < 11) {
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    badge2.setText(String.valueOf(batteryPercent));
    badge2.setTextSize(12);
    badge2.show();

    menuItemBattery.setActionView(container);

    //subject
    if (!GlobalVars.subjectGUID.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { 
        MenuItem menuItemSubject = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Subject");
        count++;
        menuItemSubject.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_person));
        menuItemSubject.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        ImageButton iconViewSubject = new ImageButton(this);
        iconViewSubject.setImageDrawable(menuItemSubject.getIcon());
        container.addView(iconViewSubject);
        menuItemSubject.setActionView(container);
    }

    //new data
    if (GlobalVars.newdata.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) { 

        MenuItem menuItemNewData = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"New Data");
        count++;
        menuItemNewData.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
        menuItemNewData.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);     
        ImageButton iconViewNewData = new ImageButton(this);
        iconViewNewData.setImageDrawable(menuItemNewData.getIcon());
        container.addView(iconViewNewData);
        menuItemNewData.setActionView(container);

    }  

    //Airplane Mode
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (noConnectivity && airplaneModeOn) {

        MenuItem menuItemAirplane = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Airplane Mode");
        count++;
        menuItemAirplane.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_airplane_mode_on));
        //menuItemAirplane.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        ImageButton iconView = new ImageButton(this);
        iconView.setImageDrawable(menuItemAirplane.getIcon());
        menuItemAirplane.setActionView(container);

    }


    return true;
}
```

LogCat:

```
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at    android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3426)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3361)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3210)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3155)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.addItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:129)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:103)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:188)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:244)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:946)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:969)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:450)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-30 09:55:26.277: E/AndroidRuntime(10834):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

**EDIT:** Looking at the source code of the problem, it seems that the problem is here:

```
 /**
 * Add an item view at the given index.
 *
 * @param itemView View to add
 * @param childIndex Index within the parent to insert at
 */
protected void addItemView(View itemView, int childIndex) {
    final ViewGroup currentParent = (ViewGroup) itemView.getParent();
    if (currentParent != null) {
        currentParent.removeView(itemView); //INDEX OUT OF BOUNDS 
    }
    ((ViewGroup) mMenuView).addView(itemView, childIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't have a parent for all of the menu items, just some of them.  Adding a layout to each item prevented IndexOutOfBounds.  Code:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem menuItemNewData;
    MenuItem menuItemSubject;
    MenuItem menuItemBattery;
    MenuItem menuItemAirplane;

    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
    container.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.headerPalePurple));

    int count = 0;

    //Battery///////////////////////////
    menuItemBattery = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Battery Level");
    menuItemBattery.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_battery));
    count++;
    menuItemBattery.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    // The badge view requires target view (iconView in this case)
    // to have a ViewGroup parent


    ImageButton iconViewBattery = new ImageButton(this);
    iconViewBattery.setImageDrawable(menuItemBattery.getIcon());
    container.addView(iconViewBattery);
    BadgeView badge2 = new BadgeView(this, iconViewBattery);
    if (batteryPercent > 30) {      
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    } else if (batteryPercent > 10 && batteryPercent < 31) {
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (batteryPercent < 11) {
        badge2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        badge2.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    badge2.setText(String.valueOf(batteryPercent));
    badge2.setTextSize(12);
    badge2.show();

    menuItemBattery.setActionView(container); 

    //subject
    if (!GlobalVars.subjectGUID.equalsIgnoreCase("")) { 
        LinearLayout container2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        container2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        container2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.headerPalePurple)); 
        menuItemSubject = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Subject");
        menuItemSubject.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_person));
        ImageButton iconViewSubject = new ImageButton(this);
        iconViewSubject.setImageDrawable(menuItemSubject.getIcon());
        container.addView(iconViewSubject);
        count++;

        menuItemSubject.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menuItemSubject.setActionView(container2);
    }

    //new data
    if (GlobalVars.newdata.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) { 
        LinearLayout container3 = new LinearLayout(this);
        container3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        container3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.headerPalePurple)); 
        menuItemNewData = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"New Data");
        menuItemNewData.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
        ImageButton iconViewNewData = new ImageButton(this);
        iconViewNewData.setImageDrawable(menuItemNewData.getIcon());
        container.addView(iconViewNewData);
        //container.addView((View)menuItemNewData);
        count++;

        menuItemNewData.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);     

        menuItemNewData.setActionView(container3);

    }  

    //Airplane Mode
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (noConnectivity && airplaneModeOn) {
        LinearLayout container4 = new LinearLayout(this);
        container4.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        container4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.headerPalePurple));
        menuItemAirplane = menu.add(0,Menu.NONE,count,"Airplane Mode");
        menuItemAirplane.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_airplane_mode_on));

        ImageButton iconViewAirplane = new ImageButton(this);
        iconViewAirplane.setImageDrawable(menuItemAirplane.getIcon());
        container4.addView(iconViewAirplane);
        count++;

        menuItemAirplane.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        menuItemAirplane.setActionView(container4);

    } 

    return true;

}
```